# rosrun crash on auto-complete (tab)

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

dear all,

i am using ros kinetic and  ubuntu 16.04. since a few days I recognize the fact that if I hit tab after typing rosrun to see the available packages the console freezes and dies after a few seconds. when I remove the catkin workspace  from the .bashrc I do not see that phenomena.

I am grateful for any hints

gerald

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274996/rosrun-crash-on-auto-complete-(tab)/) by [gsteinbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32502/gsteinbauer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2017-11-05

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-05**:
First things first: try to `rm -rf` your `build` and `devel` directories. Does `rosrun` still crash? If not, build your workspace again, `source` it and try `rosrun` again.

**Comment by [gsteinbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32502/gsteinbauer/) on 2017-11-06**:
I tried this already. If I remove the sourcing of the devel folder rosrun does not crash. If I build and add it as suggested I see the same crashing behavior. It's really wired as the catkin workspace is empty - containing no packages at all.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-06**:
Then we're going to need more info: how did you install ROS, which platform is this (`amd64`, `arm`, something else). What is the output of `env | grep -i ros | sort` both *with* and *without* `source`-ing any `setup.bash`. How did you create your workspace, what does it contain (any pkgs), etc.

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-12-27**:
@gsteinbauer Did you find the solution for this problem?
I am facing the same issue

**Comment by [supermedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34847/supermedo/) on 2018-07-08**:
@vacky11 I cannot reproduce this, but deleting contents of /var/crash solved it for me.

**Comment by [mlautman](https://answers.ros.org/users/35816/mlautman/) on 2018-07-31**:
I am having the same problem. I have tried deleting the contents of `/var/crash` and `catkin clean -y && catkin build` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also got this problem and I try to reinstall ros  in the base of the crashed ros.  fowllowed by the http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu this problem is solved.

Hope above helps you.

---

Originally posted by [Jonyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/38590/jonyu/) with karma: 23 on 2018-11-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [srlessard](https://answers.ros.org/users/44047/srlessard/) on 2019-07-12**:
Worked for me too

**Comment by [Anubhav Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/44804/anubhav-singh/) on 2020-02-24**:
I think it worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've sieeen a similar problem with autocompletion some time ago due to some wrong entries in .bashrc

See this Q&A:

https://answers.ros.org/question/204753/weird-logs-when-using-tab-completion-on-rosrun/

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2018-11-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reinstalling ROS bash worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-kinetic-rosbash
```

---

Originally posted by [Anchellon](https://answers.ros.org/users/40786/anchellon/) with karma: 51 on 2019-09-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1